# Angular UI Datepicker not functioning

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

No errors in the Javascript console, all resources seem to be loading, but the datepicker doesn't pop up when the input text field is clicked.

app.js

```
 var app = angular.module('appform', ['ngSanitize','ui.bootstrap', 'leaflet-directive']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/landmark-list.html', controller: LandmarkListCtrl}). 
}]);
```

HTML

```
    <div class="control-group input-append">
      <input type="text" ng-model="landmark.time.start" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" bs-datepicker>
      <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
    </div>
```

index.html Resources

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
  <link href="css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/ui-bootstrap-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular-leaflet-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

Comment: Without a live reproduce scenario using http://plnkr.co/ (or similar) it will be next to impossible to help you on this one.

Comment: Isn't datepicker supposed to be an element, not an attribute?

Comment: I think you've mixed 2 libraries: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap and AngularStrap - those are 2 completely different libraries but both have datepicker. Which one did you intend to use?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, but I thought this may help some in the future. I found that flat-ui CSS and angular ui's datepicker do not behave well with each other. I faced the same issue and through trial and error found that removing flat-ui.css from my imports made the datepicker appear.

The solution that worked for me was to add the following custom css.

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```